# Invalid JSON response when there are no records in the database

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter and data table. I am able to display records from the database in the list when the records are available.
but when there are no records available then I am getting the JSON error.

> DataTables warning: table id=tableId - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I tried my code

Controller

```
public function MembershipList(){
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $books=$this->Fees_model->MembershipList();

    $draw = 1;
    $recordsTotal = count($books);
    $recordsFiltered = count($books);
    $n=1;
    $data = array();
    if(!empty($books)){
           foreach($books as $row)  
           {  
               $action='<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->clubMembershipFees_id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Edit</button>';

                $data[] = array(
                     "Sr_No" => $n,
                    "Duration" => $row->Duration,
                    "PrimaryMember" => $row->PrimaryMember,
                    "action" => $action
                    );
            $n++;  
          }
    }

    else{
        echo "no data available";
    }
 $output = array(
               "draw" => $draw,
              "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
               "recordsFiltered" =>$recordsFiltered,
              "data" => $data
           );
           echo json_encode($output); 
            exit;

  }
```

ajax

```
$('#Membershiplist').DataTable({  
       "processing":true,  
       //"serverSide":true,  
       "ordering": false, 

       "ajax":{  
            url:baseUrl+ "/controller_one/MembershipList",  
            type:"POST",
            dataSrc: function (json) {
              return json;
            }
       },  
       "columns": [
                {"data":"Sr_No"},
                { "data": "Duration" },
                { "data": "PrimaryMember" },
                { "data": "action" }

          ]
       //"emptyTable":     "No record found",
  });
```

can you help me out where I am wrong ? I am getting the response in the network tab `"no data available{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[]}"`

After suggested by  @Shashidhara

```
console.log(json); output


{…}
​
data: (1) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
Sr_No: 1
action: "<button type=\"button\" name=\"update\" id=\"1\" class=\"btn btn-warning btn-xs update\">Edit</button>"
Duration: "2019-2020"
PrimaryMember: "100"

<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
length: 1
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
draw: 1
​
recordsFiltered: 1
​
recordsTotal: 1
```

Comment: You need to write the logic properly. There is some mistake in code. Both the cases,  you need to send proper json, you are using `echo 'no ...'`

Comment: just remove else part:

else{
        echo "no data available";
    }

Comment: Not the right way to do this but this will point you to the issue in your code.

Add an `exit()` right after `echo "no data available";` to avoid executing other code.

Then wrap the `no data avaiable` in a `json_encode()` to give your the right JSON format.

Comment: @lthh89vt, Can you share some example?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public function MembershipList(){
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $books=$this->Fees_model->MembershipList();

    $draw = 1;
    $recordsTotal = count($books);
    $recordsFiltered = count($books);
    $n=1;
    $data = array();
    if(!empty($books)){
           foreach($books as $row)  
           {  
               $action='<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->clubMembershipFees_id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Edit</button>';

                $data[] = array(
                     "Sr_No" => $n,
                    "Duration" => $row->Duration,
                    "PrimaryMember" => $row->PrimaryMember,
                    "action" => $action
                    );
            $n++;  
          }
    }  

    $output = array(
               "draw" => $draw,
              "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
               "recordsFiltered" =>$recordsFiltered,
              "data" => $data
           );
    echo json_encode($output); 

  }
```

Javascript:

```
dataSrc: function (json) {
     var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
     return jsonData.data;
}
```

Comment: Let me try your answer, give me some time to check

Comment: Yes, now I am not getting an error, but my array not displaying when there is a record. I try to display print_r($books); then I am getting my array.

Comment: Please try using `console.log(json)` in dataSrc function. Confirm whether you are getting data.

Comment: Should I use like this?  "dataSrc": console.log(json)

Comment: I am getting the error in the console after adding your script code "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: I just comment out the datasrc, I mean I removed  from AJAX and it's working.